# Early submission of graduate school application

Tags: graduate-admissions

I may have a reason to submit my application as much as three months before the deadline. I am wondering if this would significantly hinder the odds of admission?

Answer (score 2):

If it is open for submissions then early or not won’t make a difference.

If it is not yet open then it is up to them what they will do.

Comment: In particular, you can't expect anyone to look at your application before the actual deadline.  Depending on the application system, the admissions committee may not even notice that you submitted it early.